# how to extract index in factor vector in Rpy2

Tags: python, r, vector, rpy2

I have a factor vector sv='ababbc' and a integer vector fv=[1,1,1,1,1,1]. fv is correspond to sv.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
sv=robjects.StrVector('ababbc')
fac=robjects.FactorVector(sv)
fv=robjects.r['rep'](1,6)
```

I want to change the value of element to 2 in fv, which of index correspond to letter “a”.
made fv=[2,1,2,1,1,1]

How to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the index when true:

```
In [54]:
import numpy as np
np.argwhere(np.array(sv) == 'a')
Out[54]:
array([[0],
       [2]])
```

The 1st and 3rd positions have the letter 'a'.

You can't do that with `fac`, as it is already factorized and contains only the levels, 1, 2, 3..., not the original 'a', 'b', 'c'... anymore.

```
In [55]:

np.argwhere(np.array(fac) == 'a')
Out[55]:
array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64)
In [56]:

np.array(fac)
Out[56]:
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Or it can be done in `R` side:

```
In [51]:

robjects.reval('result1 <- which(sv %in% c("a"))')
print robjects.r.result1
[1] 1 3
```

To systematically assign a given value to a level, I suggest you to use the [`factor`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/factor) function in `R`:

```
In [53]:
robjects.r.assign('sv',  sv)
robjects.reval('result3 <- factor(sv, levels=c("a","b","c"), labels=c(10,2,3))')
print robjects.r.result3
[1] 10 2  10 2  2  3 
Levels: 10 2 3
```

So `a` gets `10`, `b` gets `2`, `c` gets `3` and so on.

Comment: what is "np"? I have another FloatVector which correspond to fac, so I want to extract the satisfied index. Thank you.

Comment: `np` is `numpy` package. Edited that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another FloatVector fv which correspond to fac, how can I extract the correspond element in  fv which index correspond to the satisfied index in sv?

Comment: You can use `np.array(fv)[np.argwhere(np.array(sv) == 'a')].flatten()`. You can skip `flatten()` if you don't mind getting a 2d-array.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it still not solve my problem. I made the question more specific, would you help me?

Comment: In that case, my suggestion is that you may want to construct your factor vector that way in the 1st place, rather than construct it first and change it later, see edit.